# Correct way to add PHP variable in MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am very new to PHP and trying to select data from a MySQL field (in a table). I used the following query.

```
$token = $wpdb->query("SELECT ami_st_token_aut 
                         FROM $wpdb->users 
                        WHERE ID = '".$current_user->ID."' ");
```

The value in the ami_st_token_aut is a big number but when i echo $token, it is echoing out `$current_user->ID` instead of the big token number. What could be going wrong?

Comment: It's not quite PHP but rather wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways of doing it.

If you're doing it with WordPress, use the `wpdb->prepare` function:

```
$token = $wpdb->get_var(
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT ami_st_token_aut FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID=%d", $current_user->ID
  )
);
```

If you're doing it without Wordpress, use the `mysql_real_escape_string` function.

```
mysql_query(
  "SELECT ami_st_token_aut FROM tablename WHERE ID='" 
  . mysql_real_escape_string($ID) . "'"
);
```

Comment: @Sam: +1 Usually means you also give him one (I did and he reached 1 so I guess you didn't) and you should accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I couldn't give hime 1 because my rep is less than 15.

Answer (score 1):

See [the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class).

The `$wpdb->query` function returns the number of rows that matched your query (if you do a SELECT, anyway).

`$wpdb->get_var` is the function to use to get a single value from the database.